# DrawingImage always draws in upper left, regardless of coordinates supplied

Tags: wpf, image, drawing

I'm attempting to draw a set of images in an `Image` in WPF, potentially off from top left, but no matter what I do, either the `Image`, the `DrawingImage` or the `DrawingGroup` are causing the image that is closest to the top left corner to default to the top left corner of the image.

Here's the code:

XAML:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="1" Name="Canvas">
    <Image Name="imgLevel">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                 <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                      <DrawingGroup>
                           <ImageDrawing Rect="120, 120, 100, 100" ImageSource="" />
                           <ImageDrawing Rect="300, 300, 100, 100" ImageSource="" />
                       </DrawingGroup>
                 </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

No matter what I set the coordinates to for the first `ImageDrawing`, it's always in the upper left corner.

Is there a way to override this behaviour?  More importantly, I eventually want to be able to specify negative numbers to that Rect.  Is this possible?

Comment: So, the canvas was causing the move to upper left, but removing the canvas still has one of the classes assuming it knows better where to place images, and it's letting me push them outside the bounds of the control.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't use the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top attached properties on the Image control? Like this:

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image Canvas.Left="-5" Canvas.Top="-10" Name="imgLevel">
        <Image.Source>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Eventually I'm hoping to have multiple images which will be added / removed from the drawing group when they come in and out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Add something to your drawing group which is positioned at your desired top-left (for example a RectangleGeometry which covers the whole area you want, but has a Transparent brush).

Then when the DrawingImage gets the bounds of the whole group, it will be forced to at least the size of your 'invisible' geometry.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me why, but placing a one-pixel wide Rectangle (using a nonvisible brush) into the origin of the DrawingGroup solves this problem. It would be good to know what rules govern this behavior in WPF.